# How should I store these objects in SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So I have a class named A:

```
public class A{
    private String A1;
    private String A2;
    private String A3;
    private String A4;
    private B A5;
    private B A6;
}
```

That as you can see contains some strings and 2 B class typed object. The B class:

```
public class B{
    private ArrayList<C> B1;
}
```

Contains 1 arraylist of C elements. The C class:

```
public class C{
    private String C1;
    private ArrayList<D> C2;
```

A string and arraylist of D objects. The D class:

```
public class D{
    private String D1;
    private Boolean D2;
}
```

I get the data from JSON files, I build up an arraylist out of A objects, but I should store it in a database because I do not want to download the data every time the user opens the application...

Comment: Use ORM or realm instead of using sqlite.. you can store object directly using realm https://realm.io/blog/realm-for-android/

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to store non-atomic values into a relational database. You must normalize it using multiple tables which relate to each other using foreign keys. Quite a tedious task to do.

Perhaps you can store the object itself using serialization - [resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/store.html)

Answer (score 0):

You just want to store the custom model object into a database so for this you can use room Persistence database by Google.
Check the following link: [local database using Roome](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/)